# Bash regex directory rename

Tags: regex, bash

I have directories in the form of

`*Var0.5Def1Min1, *Var0.5Def1Min2, ... , *Var0.5Def10Min100`

I only want to rename the part with **Var0.5** to **Var0.50**

Examples: 
`*Var0.5Def1Min1 > *Var0.50Def1Min1` , 
`*Var0.5Def10Min100 > *Var0.50Def10Min100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in *Var*; do mv $i ${i/Var0.5/Var0.50} ; done
Var0.50Def1Min1
Var0.50Def10Min100
```

This is using brace expansion technique.

**Example:**

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  eng  68 Jan 24 12:31 Var0.5Def10Min100
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  eng  68 Jan 24 12:30 Var0.5Def1Min1
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ for i in *Var*; do mv $i ${i/Var0.5/Var0.50} ; done
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  eng  68 Jan 24 12:31 Var0.50Def10Min100
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  eng  68 Jan 24 12:30 Var0.50Def1Min1
```

Comment: i think your one is much lean

Comment: I used yours ajreal Thanks, because I saw it first, but agreed this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should try [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename), part of util-linux(-ng).